# Как писать Native программы?

Tags: c++, windows, native, visual-studio-2019

Подскажите где можно почитать про написание Native программ (которые можно запустить до запуска графической оболочки Windows). Пока только нагуглил, что для этого требуется WDK, но после установки в студии (2019) появились готовые варианты только для драйверов. Насколько я понял подобный драйвер можно перенастроить как Native приложение, но как?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: нативные и до запуска винды?

Comment: Имеется ввиду такие, которые можно запустить из консоли восстановления?

Comment: Те, что можно добавить в регистрах в boot execute.

Answer (score 1):

Для этого необходимо выставить в свойстввах проекта соответствующую [подсистему](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/subsystem-specify-subsystem?view=vs-2019):

```
/SUBSYSTEM:NATIVE
```

Однако *"которые можно запустить до запуска Windows"* это скорее не NATIVE подсистема, а одна из EFI_*.